# iOS Accessibility in UICollectionView: VoiceOver gets stuck on last cell

Tags: ios, swift, uiaccessibility

I'm trying to get accessibility to work in my app. I want the exact same behavior as the "App Store" app, in the "Featured" page:

A `tableview` where each row contains a `collectionView` with some cells. I want to use VoiceOver to go thru all of the cells of a `collectionView`, then move to the next `collectionView's` cells.

The VoiceOver works when I swipe right and moves from cell to cell. The problem is that once I reach the last cell of a `collectionView`, instead of moving to the next `collectionView`, the VoiceOver gets stuck on that last cell. The app doesn't crash but stops responding.

I'm using this code in the UICollectionViewCell subclass to get the `collectionView` to scroll right when I reach the last visible cell:

```
override func accessibilityElementDidBecomeFocused() {
    let cv = self.superview as! UICollectionView
    let path = cv.indexPath(for: self)!
    if self == cv.visibleCells.last {
        cv.scrollToItem(at: path, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
        UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification, self)
    }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe implement `- (BOOL)accessibilityScroll:(UIAccessibilityScrollDirection)direction`